# Is there any reason to put 2 GFCI outlets in a 2-gang outlet box?

Tags: electrical

Is there a downside to using a single GFCI plus a regular receptacle in a 2-gang box?

This is in a bathroom, in LA County, and the work will be inspected, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as the second standard receptacle is correctly connected to the GFCI receptacle as well as properly labeled with the usual "GFCI Protected" sticker, it should be acceptable for code.

The downside is it will look awkward and you should think more about if saving the small amount of extra money for an additional GFCI receptacle will be worth it.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure whether it was standard practice or not. I will just use two GFCIs.

Comment: Look Awkward?  If you match the second outlet with a decora style (single rectangle instead of the two ovals) it looks perfectly normal.  Plus it saves 10-15 dollars on the install.

Comment: Good call on the decorators receptacle. Only saves $5 though- not $10-$15.

Comment: @paulmz , working from memory.  But I believe Decora outlets are $2 and GFCI are $15 in my area.

Comment: I checked a store's website before posting: $3.50 for a tamper-resistant decorators duplex and $8.50 for a tamper-resistant GFCI receptacle.

Comment: @paulmz - so local differences in price.  Out of curiosity, I looked up prices on home depot (local big box store for me), Single Decora Oulet is $2.68 USD and cheapest single GFCI is $13.97 USD.

Comment: @diceless - yes, local prices certainly are different. My prices are from Menards.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a washer and dryer both requiring GFCI protection by code. If you put in two GFCI receptacles side by side then you would spread the load to each separate receptacle. Washers and dryers are typically in the 6 amp range (unless it's an all electric dryer, those are in the 25 amp range). So putting a washer and dryer on one GFCI receptacle can put 12 amps (6 plus 6 amps) at once to that GFCI.  Most GFCI are rated 15 amps, so you're legal. However that's a lot of stress on that 15 amps GFCI. Two side-by-side GFCI receptacles would be a better choice

Comment: Makes no real difference if they're on the same circuit. After all, each is a duplex so someone could plug in a space heater or whatever. Two separate circuits has an advantage but then it is also 2nd cable and breaker